# How do I get rid of a 3D grid overlaying my artboard in Ilustrator?

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

I was creating a simple artboard in Illustrator and suddenly a 3D grid overlay appeared. I must have mistyped or something but now I'm struggling to get rid of the 3D overlay. How do I remove this overlay?

Answer (score 0):

View -> Perspective Grid -> Hide Grid